# Keycloak brute force attack: Locks account in 2 failures

Tags: keycloak, brute-force, keycloak-services

I am using Keycloak 4.8.0.Final.
I have enabled Brute Force detection from Keycloak admin with default settings.

Issue: currently it locks account in 2 subsequent login failures. Where i want it to lock after 3 login failures.

Can you help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default "Quick Login Check Milli Seconds" is 1000. That means if there are 2 failures within a one-second then the account will be locked.
It looks like you have to set the next settings:

```
Permanent Lockout = "ON"
Max Login Failures = "3"
Quick Login Check Milli Seconds = "1"
```